# Munn in the World to Come

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat, mysticism-kabbalah, mon-manna

The Rema in OC Simman 242 [brings](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.242.1) a minhag to eat "pashtidah" shabbos night in memory of the munn. The Beur Halacha is very bothered why one would do such a thing on shabbos, given that the munn specifically didn't fall on shabbos. He [brings an explanation](https://www.sefaria.org/Biur_Halacha.242.1.6) he likes from the Tosefes Shabbos citing Toras Chaim:

> והוא לפי דשבת בראשית הוא דוגמת שבת שלע"ל שהוא יום שכולו שבת ולכן אנו עושים כמה דברים בשבת זה דוגמתו היינו לאכול בשר ודגים נגד סעודת שור הבר ולויתן ומקדשין על היין נגד היין המשומר בענביו לצדיקים לע"ל...ולכך שפיר יש לעשות בשבת זכר **למן ההוא** [תוספות שבת]׃
>
> The reason is that shabbos is a sneak peek at the shabbos of Olam Haba, which is a day that is entirely shabbos. Therefore we do many things on our shabbos similar to that of the future Shabbos. Meaning, we eat meat and fish corresponding to the Shor HaBar and the Leviasan and we say kiddush on wine corresponding to the wine that is preserved for the tzaddikim in the future... therefore it is fitting to [eat pashtidah] on shabbos, commemorating **that munn**

Even though he doesn't explain it, it sounds like he is saying there will be munn in the world to come (although the word זכר seems awkward with this usage). I haven't heard of this concept before and I am wondering if this is something the Toras Chaim developed or is there an earlier source for munn in Olam haba? Not that these things are easy to understand but I'm also wondering what its purpose will be. Will it be eaten? (Chazal [say](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.17a.12) there will be no eating in Olam haba, although what's with the other foods mentioned above I'm not sure).

Comment: Unless you're using a Galitziner accent, I'm pretty sure it's _mann_ or _monn_, as the Hebrew word is spelled מָן, with a _komatz_.

Comment: @ezra transliterating is always messy business. I'm spelling it like the word "fun" / "sun", and added an extra n for emphasis

Comment: A source you might be interested in is P'ri Zaddiq of R. Zaddoq Hakohen of Lublin, (Qedushat Shabbat Ma'amar 7):
 דאכילת שבת ידוע דכולה בקדושה. והיא כאכילת מן ופירות גן עדן.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One source for this is the [Midrash Otiot D'Rabbi Akiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_of_Rabbi_Akiva) (Version A) (s.v. Uma Nishtana in Battei Midrashot Vol. II) which states:

> ומנין שהמן בשחקים והיה טחון ברחיים בשביל צדיקים ובשביל ישראל לעולם הבא שנאמר (תהלים עח) וימטר עליהם מן לאכל ודגן שמים נתן למו
>
> From where do we know that that the manna...was ground for the Jews in the World to Come? As it says (Psalms 78:24): 'And He caused manna to rain upon them for food.'

Similarly, note Yalkut Shimoni to Ezekiel (339) (and to Psalms 819) which states:

> שבו ריחים עומדות וטוחנות מן לצדיקים לעתיד לבא שנאמר ויצו

The Otiot D'Rabbi Akiva is based on Hagiga (12b) (quoted in [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87826/8775) answer), and Yalkut Shimoni is a variant of it. Importantly, while printed editions of Hagiga do not specify that the manna for the righteous will be consumed in the messianic era, this is found in manuscripts of the passage, such as Goettingen 3, Munich 6, Munich 6, and Spanish Print (ca. 1480), who state that this will be לעתיד לבא. (Notably Vatican 171 lacks these words, and matches the printed editions).

Also interesting, is a work of a student of Rashba, Torat HaMinha (Sukkot Derasha 83 pg. 742) who states that the Jews in the wilderness were treated to food and dwelling similar to Olam HaBa. The food was the manna, which Hazal state was like one sixtieth of Olam HaBa.

> והטעימן הקדוש ברוך הוא מעין העה"ב בין במאכל בין במושב. במאכל כמו שאמרנו, וארז"ל מן אחד מששים מעין העולם הבא

Answer (score 9):

Talmud Bavli ([Hagigah 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.12b?lang=bi)), from Sefaria:

> ר"ל אמר שבעה ואלו הן וילון רקיע שחקים זבול מעון מכון ערבות... שחקים שבו רחיים עומדות וטוחנות מן לצדיקים שנאמר (תהלים עח, כג) ויצו שחקים ממעל ודלתי שמים פתח 
>   וימטר עליהם מן לאכול וגו'.
>
> Reish Lakish said: There are [seven firmaments,] and they are as follows: Vilon, Rakia, Sheḥakim, Zevul, Ma’on, Makhon, and Aravot... Sheḥakim, heights, is the one in which mills stand and grind manna for the righteous, as it is stated: “And He commanded the heights [Shehakim] above, and opened the doors of heaven; and He caused manna to rain upon them for food, and gave them of the corn of heaven” (Psalms 78:23–24)

Breishit Rabbah ([48:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.48?lang=bi)) states:

> רַבִּי אֶלְעָזָר בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי סִימָאי אָמַר, אָמַר הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא לְאַבְרָהָם... אַתָּה אָמַרְתָּ וְאֶקְחָה פַּת לֶחֶם, חַיֶּיךָ שֶׁאֲנִי פּוֹרֵעַ לְבָנֶיךָ וכו', (שמות טז, ד): וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל משֶׁה הִנְנִי מַמְטִיר לָכֶם לֶחֶם מִן הַשָּׁמָיִם, הֲרֵי בַּמִּדְבָּר. בָּאָרֶץ מִנַּיִן, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר (דברים ח, ח): אֶרֶץ חִטָּה וּשְׂעֹרָה. **לֶעָתִיד לָבוֹא מִנַּיִן (תהלים עב, טז): יְהִי פִסַּת בַּר בָּאָרֶץ.**

Comment: Note that "שחקים" (vowelized differently) can also mean "grinding down".