# PTIJ: Why do Jews eat filtered fish?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Why do Jews eat filtered fish? I've noticed that they mainly eat it on Friday night, with a small piece of carrot on top.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Only Ashkenazim. Sefardim have much better taste in food than we do.

Comment: I am afraid this doesn't fit the criteria for PTIJ (misinterpret a real Torah concept or Jewish text or apply a distinctly Torah style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an irrelevant topic)

Comment: @mbloch filtered is the misinterpretation so it is a valid PTIJ

Comment: @mbloch https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5027/

Comment: cc @sabbahillel ^^

Comment: If you are interested in "halachic foods" you might enjoy [this other MY answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/68581/11501)

Answer (score 0):

One of my personal "ponders" is why manufacturers catch tuna that was already in the water, take it out of the water, then they shape it round and finally, they put in back in a can **with water** all over again.

But, being that's what it is, there are toxins all over the place, in this process. The ocean has sewage spilling into it. The tuna eats the toxins from this sewage, and tuna tends to have high levels of mercury. Then, the tap water they use to can the fish. Well, that had *better** be filtered, because then you're eating intoxicated fish.

So, in general, Jews look specifically for filtered fish, esp. when buying canned tuna and salmon or any canned fish. I would assume that jarred fish is the same. I can't say for what happens with fresh fish, but, I gather that in a kosher fish store, when they "kasher" the fish (No, it's not soaked and salted or slaughtered, but the mashgiach makes it a kosher fish, somehow) they probably filter it, too.

That's what makes eating it safe and healthy. If you've been eating non-filtered fish, I suggest that you see a good GI specialist immediately, and have a colonoscopy done.